# How does Python's unittest library match patterns passed via the -p parameter?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am running the following command to run only the tests located inside the file called `test_CO2.py`

`python3.7 -m unittest discover -s some_path/tests/ -p "*CO2*"`

My folder structure looks like the following:

```
some_path/tests/
  CO2
    test_CO2.py
  battery
    test_battery.py
  tank
    test_tank.py
```

I want to specify the tests that are ran. If for example I only wish to test the tank and CO2 code how can I do that? I thought of passing the following regex:
`\w*(CO2|tank)\w*.py` which fails to find any tests.

I am thinking that the pattern passed in to the `-p` option does not accept regex. How, then can I specify the tests I wish to run?

Comment: For what it's worth, this is _`unittest`_ parsing your `-p` params, not core Python. These are usually done via globbing, not regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to bypass this restriction from unittest.

I can run specific tests with `python3.7 -m unittest path_to_some_test`

```
# take regex and find all files that match
# clean up results. i.e. remove './' from output
test_paths_result=()
test_paths=$(find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "${regex}")
for file_path in ${test_paths}; do
  # save clean results to array variable
  test_paths_result+=("${file_path:2}")
done

echo "Running test files that match the following expression: '${regex}'"
python3.7 -m unittest ${test_paths_result[@]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally, everything you pass via the `-p` parameter into `unittest` is processed via [`TestLoader::_match_path()` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ce361d3bb15cf49b82fa03e3e593d7cbd8ee1ff/Lib/unittest/loader.py#L380) which then invokes chain of functions `fnmatch()` → `fnmatchcase()` → `_compile_pattern()` → `translate()` from [`fnmatch` library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fnmatch.html).

**The `translate()` function translates your original `-p` argument into a regex, which is then used for name-matching.**

The docs for `fnmatch()` function state this:

```
Patterns are Unix shell style:
*       matches everything
?       matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any char not in seq
```

From what I can see, this is the extent of what it can do. **All other characters are escaped to be matched literally**.

**Example:** I passed regex `a|b` as the pattern. The `translate()` function returned final regex in the form `(?s:p\|m)\Z`. There **the pipe character became escaped**.

If you're extra curious, go see `fnmatch` lib's `translate()` function [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9ce361d3bb15cf49b82fa03e3e593d7cbd8ee1ff/Lib/fnmatch.py#L74) - if you want to know the exact process of translating your "glob-like" patterns into the final regex.